# UserControl is not being destroyed when an event is attached to it

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

I have the following line of code in a usercontrol:

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown += RootClicked;
```

When it's defined the parent usercontrol is no longer collected by the GC or destroyed, the RootClicked event keeps firing even after it should no longer be active.

if I add:

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown -= RootClicked;
```

The issue is no longer present.

Any ideas why this is? Is there a function I should explicitly remove the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour and a common source of memory leaks in .NET.

When you attach an instance method of object A to an event of object B, you are adding in the list of event receivers the instance of A, so the garbage collector cannot free up the object A until you remove the handler or you release every reference to both object A and B.
This is an expected and normal behaviour.

There are two common ways to solve the problem:

1) You unsubscribe object A from the event when you don't need the object A anymore.

2) You use weak events, like WPF does.
Weak events are usually implemented with the class WeakReference, you can find more informations on the web.

Comment: ah sweet, wanted to confirm it was :) I'll mark yours as the answer once stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 2):

What happens:
Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown event keeps reference to the control in its invocation list so the control is not eligible for collection (since it is referenced by the delegate).

Solution:

Subscribe to Unloaded event after you subscribe to the MouseLeftButtonDown event and unsubscribe form the MouseLeftButtonDown event in the Unloaded event handler:

```
 ...
 Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown += RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
 this.Unloaded += Control_Unloaded;
 ...

 void Control_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown -= RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
 }
```

OR more concise:

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown += RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
this.Unloaded += (s, e) => Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown -= RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

Comment: check the documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.95).aspx What version of Silverlight are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behavior, but most developers are not aware of it.  You should look into the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) for information on how to get around this limitation in a more graceful (if more coding-intensive) fashion than having to manually remove event handlers.